# ngb-modal not opening correctly

Tags: angular, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

Copying the demo code from the modal-basic example, I'm having this problem. The modal window is displayed within the root HTML, not in a new window with a black backdrop as it should be. Any ideas? I'm using angular CLI and installed popper.js, jquery, ngb and bootstrap.

The code is absolutely the same as the first example from this URL:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

only difference is there's a (click) on a

that opens the modal but it uses the same function as the example

Here's a GIF with the problem
[The Problem Itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEKXm.gif)

Comment: are you sure you've imported the NgbModule? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: pretty sure, my app.module has   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],

Comment: imported from import { NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

Comment: and in my modal .ts I have 

import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, NgbModalOptions, NgbModalRef, ModalDismissReasons, NgbModalModule, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: from the looks of it, you seem to have not included the bootstrap css in your project. Add this in the <head></head> of your index.html: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: SOLVED! thank you so much

Comment: Glad I helped, added the comment as answer so that it can be checked answered.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you seem to have not included bootstrap css in your project.

Add this in the  of your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```